# Run command on entrypoint in docker outputs no file errors

Tags: docker

On a simple dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /code/
```

If I run:

```
docker build -t my_image .
docker run -v ~/Downloads/data/:/home -it -d my_image # mount data folder inside home
docker exec -it container_id  sh -c  "python script.py -i /home/db.sqlite"
```

Everything runs ok. But I would like to run the `script.py` on run so that there is no need for an exec command.

So I added to the dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python script.py -i /home/db.sqlite"]
```

But when I run my container now it fails with a file or folder not found error at `python script.py`

Comment: What is the output of `docker run --entrypoint "/bin/ls" container_id`? Is **script.py** there?

Comment: Just provide the full path to `script.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is how the `ENTRYPOINT` syntax works. Your using the exec-form and it does not find the binary (it uses the whole command line as path to the binary).

From https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint:

> ENTRYPOINT has two forms:
>    ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "param1",
>   "param2"] (exec form, preferred)
>   ENTRYPOINT command param1 param2
>   (shell form)

So try either:

`ENTRYPOINT ["/path/to/python", "script.py", "-i", "/home/db.sqlite"]`

Or

`ENTRYPOINT python script.py -i /home/db.sqlite`